# twitter in android

Tags: android, twitter

I need a call back URL for registration  of my app in twitter. How to get it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be kept blank also. You can override it any other time when you will be connecting to twitter from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Let me google that for you... http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

Answer (score 0):

The callback url that you enter in the twitter developers site wont be used in your actual app.
In your android manifest, you should have this code of line in an intent-filter;

```
<data android:scheme="destroy" android:host="destroytwitter" />
```

Then, in your OAuth activity, your callback URL will be "scheme://host", in this example "destroy://destroytwitter". You can put anything in scheme and host.

NB: Yep, thats a leak of my upcoming app(an android version of DT).